# Yocto failing to fetch URL not understood

Tags: python, linux, aws-cli, yocto, bitbake

I am building a Linux image using Yocto which requires the AWS CLI (Command Line INterface). I have added the *meta-iot-cloud* layer which contains the AWS CLI and SDKs etc., however there are so many other python module dependencies which I have to add one by one manually to my project

One of the dependencies is python3-six. I've located this online, both files python3-six_1.12.0.bb and python-six.inc and added them to *meta-iot-cloud/recipes-devtools/python*. The content of these files are shown below.

However I keep receiving this error during the bitbake compilation that I do not understand. I don't see this URL mentioned anywhere in the files, and don't know know why it's looking for it, and hence i've no idea how to solve this :

```
WARNING: Failed to fetch URL 
https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python3-six/python3-six- 
1.12.0.tar.gz, attempting MIRRORS if available

ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 8, output:
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/p/python3-six/python3-six- 
1.12.0.tar.gz:
2019-04-11 10:58:46 ERROR 404: Not Found.

ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure for URL: 
'https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python3-six/python3-six- 
1.12.0.tar.gz'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/ubuntu/testYoctoBuild- 
AWS_IoT/apiary-gateway/build-bbgw2/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux- 
gnueabi/python3-six/1.12.0-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.4160

ERROR: Task 5800 (/home/ubuntu/testYoctoBuild-AWS_IoT/apiary-gateway/build- 
bbgw2/../meta-iot-cloud/recipes-devtools/python/python3-six_1.12.0.bb, 
do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
```

python3-six_1.12.0.bb :

```
inherit setuptools3
require python-six.inc
```

python-six.inc :

```
SUMMARY = "Python 2 and 3 compatibility library"
HOMEPAGE = "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/"
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=83e0f622bd5ac7d575dbd83d094d69b5"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "9ae5d1feed8c0215f4ae4adcd9207fcb"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = 
"d16a0141ec1a18405cd4ce8b4613101da75da0e9a7aec5bdd4fa804d0e0eba73"

inherit pypi

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "${PYTHON_PN}-io"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

Comment: maybe you don't have the corresponding [pypi.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/pypi.bbclass?h=master-next)?

Comment: @Nayfe  I've added that file. The errors relating to pypi have disappeared but I still have issues relating to "pythonhosted" as follows      :         WARNING: Failed to fetch URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/$/python3-six/python3-six-1.12.0.tar.gz, attempting MIRRORS if available
ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 8, output:
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/$/python3-six/python3-six-1.12.0.tar.gz:
2019-04-11 16:01:01 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Comment: Which Yocto version do you use? (Mixing Poky/OE-core/meta-oe versions is quite bad). You can prolly add `PYPI_PACKAGE = "six"` in your recipe to fix this issue, but it's ugly :)

Comment: I'm actually using Yocto version Fido, which is from April 2015 :) I've inherited a project, and trying to add AWS CLI to this, but I guess it makes sense to update to the the latest stable Yocto version? Where would I put "PYPI_PACKAGE = "six" exactly? Just to see if that works first? Thanks

Comment: For instance before inherit pypi in python-six.inc

Comment: @Nayfe  It seems to have solved that problem for that recipe, but now I have other issues with different recipes :) So I guess it makes sense to start fresh with the newest Yocto version? I am completely new to Yocto so have been hacking away and not really knowing what i'm doing to be honest